# AutoFocus on Text Input in React Using Styled Components

Tags: html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, styled-components

How do you make the TextInput in React using Styled Components to be autoFocus on page load?

I did using `useEffect` but it seems it doesn't autoFocus on the TextInput. I wanted the email text input to be focus outlined on page load.

Codesandbox -> [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-custom-input-forked-xbn561?file=/src/index.js:389-699)

```
function App() {
  const emailInput = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (emailInput.current) {
      emailInput.current.focus();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
      <Input type="email" placeholder="Email" innerRef={emailInput} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the [`autofocus` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autofocus)?

Comment: @Andy. Yes. but it doesn't autofocus unless you click on it.

Comment: I see. You might have an answer below already. Just some comments: [autofocus itself is quite disputed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autofocus#accessibility_considerations), as it can disorient keyboard and screen reader users, and hide contents by the automatically opened on-screen keyboard on touchscreens. Also, [using placeholders as labels is not good for usability](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-placeholder-attribute), and quite catastrophic for accessibility.

Comment: @Andy. Understood. this was just for practice. anyway answer below still not working

Comment: You wouldn’t want focus to be set inside the input every time the component is rendered. This might be quite harmful. Page load seems a weird concept for a single page application (; So you would rather use [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) to do it once only.

Comment: @Andy, sorry I'm using react-hooks. Or can you just fork my codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

As per `styled-components` documentation, in [`innerRef` section](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#deprecated-innerref-prop), the `innerRef` is deprecated as of v4:

> **NOTE**
>
> The "innerRef" prop was removed in styled-components v4 in favor of the React 16 forwardRef API. Just use the normal ref prop instead.

Before React 16, there was no nice way to pass references up to the parent (except using callbacks). In React 16.3 [`createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref) and [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref) have been introduced for doing that, along with [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook later. Styled Components v4, has started to use that mechanism.

Therefore, you may use `ref` directly:

```
function App() {
  const emailInput = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (emailInput.current) {
      emailInput.current.focus();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
      <Input type="email" placeholder="Email" ref={emailInput} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

On the other side, if the intent is only for focusing, as stated by @Andy, the `autoFocus` property may be a better choice:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
      <Input type="email" placeholder="Email" autoFocus />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The React's `autoFocus` attribute is doing exactly the same thing as the code above (`focus` programmatically element on the mount). Do not confuse it with HTML's `autofocus` attribute, which behavior is inconsistent between browsers.

Comment: Same thing. I changed it. https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-custom-input-forked-xbn561?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @Joseph, it does work for me. Could you try to i.e. refresh the CodeSandbox preview via the refresh icon next to the "https://xbn561.csb.app/" address (or similar)? Most likely CodeSandbox is moving focus somewhere else after CodeSandbox UI is loaded. Alternatively, you may open the preview directly in browser via https://xbn561.csb.app/ link, which will not have the CodeSandbox UI.

Comment: where does useRef come from? I can’t find documentation on it, neither in React, nor in Styled Components…

Comment: @Andy, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: Would you mind linking the doc in your answer?

Comment: Probably there is a better way to do this?

Comment: @Andy, I'm not sure if it's accurate for that answer (as it's already in question), but I may elaborate a little on the forwardRef, and link to that

Comment: @Joseph, for focusing - the `autoFocus` attribute solution in React will be better, as it's doing exactly the same behavior (running `focus` on mount). In the opposite, the regular `autofocus` attribute in HTML doesn't have a consistent behavior between browsers. There is a nice explanation on https://blog.maisie.ink/react-ref-autofocus/, if you'd like to know details.